# Windows CMD - Run program and specify image name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to run a program from the commandline (or batch file) but specify the imagename that shows up in the task manager.  Is this possible using windows CMD?

This is something that needs to be done in a batch script or as a command-line argument, not by renaming the exe itself.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm curious why you want to do this?

Comment: Its kind of a strange situation.  I am running a command from within Java and I want to monitor the memory usage of this command, and then kill it if it gets too high.  The problem is I may have multiple instances of this command running so I need to know which one is which.

Comment: @ademartini, I've updated my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, I'm trying to change the title of any arbitrary command and also without renaming files.

Comment: @ademartini [This Microsoft KB article about Windows's CreateProcess function](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175986) suggests that the image path name _is_ the name of the .exe that you run, and therefore you can't change it without renaming the file. (I wouldn't be surprised if there is a way around it, but it doesn't look like a standard thing Windows can do).

Answer (score 5):

From a command prompt you can use `c:\> title MyCustomTitle` and then they show up in TaskManager (Windows 8) like this:

[image: Screenshot of Task Manager with custom title in cmd.exe]

So you could tell them apart that way. I don't know of a way to change the icon, and setting a shortcut with a custom icon doesn't work.

**EDIT**

Suggestion 2: Copy c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe and rename it, then run that.

[image: Screenshot of Task Manager with renamed cmd.exe]

**EDIT 2**

Since [This Microsoft KB Article on CreateProcess](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175986) makes me think it's not possible to do what you want, how about a WMI query that shows you running processes and their process ID, and you can run it after every launch and see what the new process ID is?

e.g. batch file

```
wmic PROCESS WHERE (Name="notepad.exe") GET ProcessId
rem up to you to keep track of previously seen processes
```

PowerShell

```
$knownProcessIds= @()
$processIds = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter 'Name="notepad.exe"' | select -ExpandProperty ProcessId
$newProcessId = $ProcessIds | ? {$knownProcessIds -notcontains $_}
$knownProcessIds += $newProcessId
Write-Output "New notepad instance is $newProcessId"
```

Comment: I think this only changes the window title. The image name still shows as the name of the executable.

Comment: @aphoria, yes, but `tasklist /v` will give you access to the window title. If you know the imagename and the window title, you know what to kill.

Comment: @aphoria oops, I was thinking of changing the icon picture, not the text name.

Comment: @MCND That's true. However, from the question, it's not clear to me if `CMD.EXE` is the executable the OP is trying to do this too. I don't think this will work for any executable.

Comment: @aphoria good suggestion; but copying and renaming should work for many executables.

Comment: @aphoria, you are right, it will only work for anything that can change/adapt the window title. I was shooting at the `(or batch file)` part of the question.